# Replace a column value by the number of other column value less then itself

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose I have a Pyspark dataframe with two columns :ID, salary. The dataframe has 100 million records. I would like to replace the column salary by the column rank-order. The column rank-order counts how many people with salary below. How to do this efficiently

For example, given the following input dataframe :

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,2000),
                        (2,500),
                        (3,1500)],
                       ['id','salary'])

df.show()

+---+------+
| id|salary|
+---+------+
|  1|  2000|
|  2|   500|
|  3|  1500|
+---+------+
```

I would get the following output :

```
results.show()

+---+----------+
| id|rank_order|
+---+----------+
|  1|         2|
|  2|         0|
|  3|         1|
+---+----------+
```

Comment: What do you mean by `people with salary below`

Comment: Please provide a sample of the input dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can use window to sort and then add row number or another way is convert to rdd then sort finally use zipWithIndex. Using window:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

window = Window \
             .orderBy(F.col('salary'))
df \
   .withColumn('salary', F.dense_rank().over(window))
```

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way to do so would be to use a window function as follows. 
Order the window by salary, and use all the rows before current row.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# You study all the rows before the current one. -1 to avoid counting current row
w = Window.orderBy('salary').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,Window.currentRow-1)

# Count salary occurences on the window : salary below current salary
results = df.withColumn('rank_order',F.count('salary').over(w))
results.show()

+---+------+----------+
| id|salary|rank_order|
+---+------+----------+
|  2|   500|         0|
|  3|  1500|         1|
|  1|  2000|         2|
+---+------+----------+
```